# How return Uni<int[]> while executing multiple queries in quarkus?

Tags: java, vert.x, quarkus

In my application I am executing two queries in one transaction, first one is select and second one is Insert but after insert I want to return ids which are inserted how can we do it?

```
public Uni<int[]> addRUnRe(int id, String ids,String owner) {
    try{
        
        String sql="SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM table1 WHERE id=$1 AND owner=$2";

        String sql2= "Insert into table2 (event_id, request_id)"
        + "  values ($1, $2) RETURNING id)";
        Uni<int[]> insertTwo = null;
        return SqlClientHelper.inTransactionUni(client, tx -> {
            Uni<Integer> insertOne = tx.preparedQuery(sql)
                    .execute(Tuple.of(id, owner)).onItem().transform(pg -> pg.iterator())
                    .onItem().transform(r -> r.hasNext() ? r.next().getInteger("c"): 0);
            

  
            int isUserAllowed = insertOne.await().indefinitely();
            
            if (isUserAllowed == 1) {
                if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(ids)){
                    String[] rids=ids.split(",");
                List<Tuple> batch = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i=0;i<rids.length;i++) {
                    Object[] array = {insertOne, rids[i]};
                    batch.add(Tuple.of(Arrays.asList(array)));
                }


                Uni<int[]> insertTwo = tx.preparedQuery(sql2)
                    .executeBatch(batch).onItem().transform(pgRowSet -> IntStream.range(0, pgRowSet.size()).toArray());
                    return insertTwo;
                }
            }

            return insertOne.and(insertTwo)
                    // Ignore the results (the two ids)
                    .onItem().ignore().andContinueWithNull();
        });
        
    }catch(Exception e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Please let me know what is wrong am I doing and how to do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

As an option, we can return the map, although in Java it is desirable to choose immutable keys for the map interface.

```
 Map<String[], Uni<int[]>>
```

And then you can get the values by using

```
map.entrySet().forEach((key, value) -> ... )
```